# How do I refer to a PouchDB as a property of an object without initializing it more than once?

Tags: javascript, pouchdb

I am creating a JavaScript object, and one property of it should refer to a PouchDB database.  I am not sure how to configure the property such that the PouchDB object is initialized only once.

I tried returning `new PouchDB('widgets')` but that initializes an object every time a call to the property happens, right?

```
var obj = {
   db: ()=>{return new PouchDB('widgets')}
}
```

Comment: Initialize `db` to `new PouchDB()` directly, and don't make it a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious way would be this:

```
var obj = {
   db: new PouchDB('widgets')
}
```

Does that not work for some reason?